# How often is `/usr/share/zoneinfo` updated?

Tags: debian, timezone

I'm installing the timezone tables on MySQL, which are generated from `/usr/share/zoneinfo` on my Debian Server.

But there is a point on the notes about ensuring I keep them up to date whenever the zoneinfo files are updated.

I've searched Google, but can't find the answer to the question:

```
How often is `/usr/share/zoneinfo` updated?
```

Is it every time that the Linux OS is updated, or is it infrequently?

Comment: Typically once or twice a year, a few weeks before switching to DST and back.  The point of these updates is to catch up with the latest changes in DST regulations of the various states.

Comment: @SatoKatsura the updates occur more often than that, there have been nine releases so far this year.

Comment: @StephenKitt Then your vantage point is closer to origin then mine.  The changes still take effect only about twice a year, plus or minus a couple of weeks, to account for regulators' political agendas. :)

Comment: @SatoKatsura Yes, and for most people the updates won't have any impact anyway! `tzdata` also lists leap seconds, so that's another two dates per year with potential changes.

Comment: Check [Debian Package Tracker: tzdata](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/tzdata) to see how often there has been updates for the package. As you can see, the unstable and testing distributions get fairly fast updates after release of [new tzdata database](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/tzdb/NEWS). The updates for stable distribution are currently about 2 years late (2021a in stable when 2022f is available).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The timezone data is updated several times a year; in the past that meant every month or thereabouts, but last year there were only three updates (in February, March and October 2017). Updates are always available from the [IANA](http://www.iana.org/time-zones), and are [made available](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/tzdata) as stable updates in Debian. While there were only three releases in 2017, there were ten releases altogether in 2016, seven in 2015, ten in 2014, nine in 2013...

If you want to set something up so that the MySQL timezone tables are updated whenever the timezone info is updated, you could look at adding a [trigger](https://wiki.debian.org/DpkgTriggers) against the `tzdata` package; that way, whenever `tzdata` is updated, the timezone tables will be updated too.

Comment: OK cheers, I assume that any new update to Debian will include the current version, so each time my server admin updates the OS the `tzdata` package will be updated automatically (and I need to update the tables)?

Comment: Given the schedule, if you're updating for point releases (rather than tracking `stable-updates`) then yes, I'd imagine every point release will include `tzdata` updates.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automate the [import of the data](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_tzinfo_to_sql/) only when it is changed, ([for example using Ansible](https://git.coop/webarch/mariadb/blob/master/tasks/tz.yml)), then you can use the latest date from the `/usr/share/doc/tzdata/changelog.Debian.gz` file:

```
dpkg-parsechangelog -l /usr/share/doc/tzdata/changelog.Debian.gz -S Date
Tue, 17 Sep 2019 22:51:05 +0200
```